# body class according to number of published custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, body-class

Is it possible to add a number to the body class according to how many custom posts a current user has published, e.g. CUSTOMPOST-4

Comment: What do you mean by "current user"?

Comment: the current logged in user/author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to functions.php

```
function wpc_body_class_section($classes) {  
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {        
        $classes[] = 'CUSTOMPOST-'.count_user_posts(get_current_user_id());
    } 

    return $classes;  
}  
add_filter('body_class','wpc_body_class_section');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count_user_posts`

See:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/

Edit:

```
<?php
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
       $count_class = 'CUSTOMPOST-'.count_user_posts(get_current_user_id());
    }
?>
<body <?php body_class($count_class); ?>>
```

Something like this in your `header`

Comment: How would I use that function to add it to the body class?

Comment: See the edit, included the example code